# Using different XML layouts for different Android screens?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm a beginner to Android, and I'm trying to get a couple of buttons to line up perfectly. I've done so right here:

[image: One size]

And here's the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Scientific">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="63dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="63dip"
    android:layout_height="63dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="63dip"
    android:layout_height="63dip"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_width="63dip"
    android:layout_height="63dip"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button01"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button04"
    android:layout_width="63dip"
    android:layout_height="63dip"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button03"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button03"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button03"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button03"
    android:layout_width="63dip"
    android:layout_height="63dip"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button02"
    android:text="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is, this code does not position 5 buttons perfectly across the bottom of the screen *across different screen sizes*:

[image: Different Devices]

Reading up on the official Android developers site, I gathered that I might need different activity layouts for small, normal, large, and xlarge screen sizes. I also read something about using layout_weight in LinearLayout. What's the right way to go? Could I have some example code, if possible?

EDIT:

I would also like the buttons to scale in height so that the same amount of buttons can fit vertically across devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some insight from @Raghunandan, I was able to achieve, essentially, a table of buttons that scale up and down the same way, by using multiple LinearLayouts, each with layout_weight of 1, inside another LinearLayout. Then, inside each LinearLayout, I placed several buttons, also with layout_weight of 1

Answer (score 3):

Use a LinearLayout for buttons use layout_weight

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Scientific">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="63dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_height="63dip"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_height="63dip"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button02"

    android:layout_height="63dip"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button04"
    android:layout_height="63dip"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button03"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="63dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="1" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good, but how can I also make the buttons scale in height, so that I can fit the same amount of buttons vertically across devices?

Comment: @Hmir specify custom height for the button in different layouts. Also in landscape and portrait

Comment: @Hmir what you want is rows and columns of buttons ??

Comment: Yes, @Raghunandan basically a grid of buttons scaled to take up the same space on different devices. Should I use several Linear Layouts for this?

Comment: @Hmir use table layout can specify the number of rows and columns and set the height and width of tablelayout. grid of button yes but you can't specify number of rows you can only specify number of columns

Comment: Ok, i'll try the table layout

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot id in different layouts can be same

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot what? It will. for the same layout you can't haveids same for different views. for different layouts you can.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot you check the topic id http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html for clear understanding. And post a new question. Comments can't solve your problem. is it? R u guessing!!!

Answer (score 0):

try adding `same layout_weight` to all your `buttons`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button03"
    android:layout_width="63dip"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_height="63dip"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button02"
    android:text="1" />
```

P.S : `layout_weight` does not work with `Relative Layout`, you would have to use a `linear layout with orientation: horizontal`

When you use `android:layout_weight` you should set `android:layout_width="0dp"` (in case when vertical orientation - `android:layout_height="0dp"`).

Answer (score 0):

Depend on what screen size you support, you need to specify the appropriate screen layouts. I think you should start with this article first: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```